# PostgreSQL: could not load library llvmjit.so

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

My project was running fine. Then i opened my editor after a while and called my api then they are giving me this error. I don't know what is causing it.

> Exception Value:
> could not load library "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so":
> dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/13/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so, 10): Symbol
> not found: ____chkstk_darwin
> Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/13/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> in /Library/PostgreSQL/13/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so

[Debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BscL.png)

Comment: Possibly related to [this blog post](https://briandfoy.github.io/postgres-can-t-find-llvmjit-so/) which also does not have an answer.